# Turn Old Laptops Into Kiosks

Tags: google-chrome, disk-image, kiosk

We have several old laptops (4-5 years) that were deployed with Windoze.  I'd like to install Ubuntu on them and do something like this:

1. Boot to a fresh install each time
2. Restrict Chrome to only a few sites, mostly intranet sites
3. Delete all cookies on exit
4. Automatically reboot daily
5. Restrict all other services

Has anyone done something like this?
Thanks!

Comment: https://obrienlabs.net/setup-kiosk-ubuntu-chromium/  https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/ https://www.ryadel.com/en/linux-auto-reboot-shutdown-cron-job-crontab-task-scheduler/ and https://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/ may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Those are extremely helpful.  Sometimes, I just need a little nudge with what Google terms work.  These are perfect!

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, but I truly appreciate K7AAY's help.

Comment: I revised the subject line to make it clearer what the post is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K7AAY's comment was right on the money!
These two sites helped solve it too:

Building a kiosk computer with Ubuntu 14.04 and Chrome
https://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/

Allow of Block Access in Chrome
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532419?hl=en